# Can't log in to fbchat error in client.py

Tags: python

I have downloaded the fbchat, and trying to log in and evidently I am doing something wrong.
I am trying just to log in and it's not working.
It show error in client.py on line 206 and 151. I didn't change anything there.

I tried it with `'` or `"`. None of that worked.

What is the problem then?

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *
client = Client('my email', 'my password')
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\pycharm\mess\venv\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_client.py", line 206, in login
    self._state = State.login(
  File "C:\Documents\pycharm\mess\venv\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_state.py", line 151, in login
    raise _exception.FBchatUserError(

Comment: Maybe you could put it in the original question. Seems like it's an error happening inside of fbchat library itself, but without a full traceback it's a bit of a crystal ball debugging :D